# How to replace to_timestamp('some value') with GETDATE() string in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have thousands of line having different time value like **to_timestamp('14/03/18 07:46:33,573000000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF')**, and I want to replace all this with a single string say GETDATE().

for example i have following entries in my file,

```
to_timestamp('14/03/18 07:46:33,573000000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF')

to_timestamp('14/03/18 08:45:34,342000000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF')

to_timestamp('04/01/18 18:15:08,119000000','DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF')
```

Now I would like to replace all of them with GETDATE() string like below

```
GETDATE()

GETDATE()

GETDATE()
```

How I can achive this with Notepas++ with regular expression ? or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any other function like this you can simply use regex `(to_timestamp\(.*?\))`

If it wants to be specific then use,

`(to_timestamp\('\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+','DD\/MM\/RR\sHH24:MI:SSXFF'\))` and replace with `GETDATE\(\)`

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/5d9pl8/2)

Comment: This doesn't work with Notepad++. You have to escape the parentheses in the replacement part.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex `to_timestamp\(.*\)`